# Migrating a column of JSON string to a SQL table with just queries

Tags: sql, database, database-migration, data-migration

I have a column in a table which contains JSON string in the following format.

[Click Here for image of  JSON column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujq40.png)

> {"uuid":"633ba45145f58a40","model":"HM NOTE
>   1LTE","platform":"Android","version":"4.4.4","frontCameraAvailable":"true"}

Now I wanted to migrate this data to a table with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE OfflineAppDeviceInfo (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  deviceId INT NOT NULL,
  uuid VARCHAR(255),
  model VARCHAR(65),
  platform VARCHAR(65),
  version VARCHAR(65),
  frontCameraAvailable BIT,
  FOREIGN KEY (deviceId) REFERENCES DeviceSecurity (deviceId)
);
```

[Click here for OfflineAppDeviceInfo table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLmj4.png)

Now i already have a SQL script which parses the JSON

```
select d.deviceID,NAME,StringValue
from DeviceSecurity d
cross apply udf_parseJSON_support(d.deviceInfoJson)
where name != '-'
and d.deviceInfoJson is not null
```

[Click here for the result of the above script being run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8bXl.png)

But how do I migrate it into **OfflineAppDeviceInfo** table with just using SQL script.I know this can be done with a JAVA code, but I have a requirement that this is to be done with only SQL. Is this even possible?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What is the database?

Comment: MS SQL Server, I have jdbc:jtds:sqlserve in the DB url

Comment: You can use the `PIVOT` function from MSSQLServer to transform your rows in columns and so do a `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

Comment: Use your SQL script which parses the JSON and `INSERT` the `VALUES` in the database. I seem to miss your problem?

Comment: @StefanM The problem that JSON parsing script gives me multiple row corresponding to one deviceID , i want them in one row to insert them. I am not too good with sql, I dont know how to go about this.

Comment: PIVOT https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho  Hey , i got it work with PIVOT function, i did not know such a thing existed , thank you soo much,I learned something new today :)

Comment: @NevinSunny I'm happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this. When you prepare a valid query you can use INSERT INTO statment to copy data into the right table.

```
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @json =  
    N'[  
           { "id" : 2,"info": { "name": "John", "surname": "Smith" }, "age": 25 },  
           { "id" : 5,"info": { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith" }, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00" }  
     ]'  

    SELECT *  
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
      WITH (id int 'strict $.id',  
            firstName nvarchar(50) '$.info.name', lastName nvarchar(50) '$.info.surname',  
            age int, dateOfBirth datetime2 '$.dob')
```

Example comes from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server

Comment: OPENJSON need a database Compatibility level 130.

Comment: Yes, you right. If you see some lower version (e.g. 11.xxx) OPENJSON is not supported.